# Get a value on MouseEvent in Swing

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt

It might be a stupid question to ask.. But I see it as.....

Usually we write java code for app named; calculator and we can find may on net. But this one might be a different.
I can assure you for that::

**What I am thinking of is making the outputtext field as editable one**
 Now what I mean by OUTPUT TEXT FIELD as editable .
We enter out a number followed by a operator(*,+,-,/) any one of these and then a number and this goes on. We get a result when we click '='.
Here suppose if any number entered is incorrect. It is like I was supposed to enter 5 but I entered 3 due to which my end result is incorrect so then and there I click on 3 and get a popup window i.e popupTrigger in MouseEvent and Edit 3 to 5 and recalculation is done once  click 'oK' in popup.

```
  import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Container;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.Font;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.awt.Toolkit;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JTextField;
    import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

    public class Calculator extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
        JButton btn1 = new JButton("1");
     JButton btn2 = new JButton("2");
     JButton btn3 = new JButton("3");
     JButton btn4 = new JButton("4");
     JButton btn5 = new JButton("5");
     JButton btn6 = new JButton("6");
     JButton btn7 = new JButton("7");
     JButton btn8 = new JButton("8");
     JButton btn9 = new JButton("9");
     JButton btn0 = new JButton("0");
     JButton btnC = new JButton("C");
     JButton btnP = new JButton(".");
     JButton opPlus = new JButton("+");
     JButton opMult = new JButton("x");
     JButton opDivi = new JButton("/");
     JButton opMinu = new JButton("-");
     JButton Equal = new JButton("=");
     JTextField txt = new JTextField();
     JTextField txt2 = new JTextField();
     JTextField txtotp = new JTextField();
     List<String> enterdVal = new ArrayList<String>();
     JButton btn = new JButton("random");




     double fnum,snum,total;
         String op = null;
         private final JTextField textField = new JTextField();


        public Calculator() {
        Container c = getContentPane();

      c.setLayout(null);
      c.setBackground(Color.MAGENTA); 
      btn1.addActionListener(this);
      btn2.addActionListener(this);
      btn3.addActionListener(this);
      btn4.addActionListener(this);
      btn5.addActionListener(this);
      btn6.addActionListener(this);
      btn7.addActionListener(this);
      btn8.addActionListener(this);
      btn9.addActionListener(this);
      btn0.addActionListener(this);
      btnC.addActionListener(this);
      btnP.addActionListener(this);
      opPlus.addActionListener(this);
      opMult.addActionListener(this);
      opDivi.addActionListener(this);
      opMinu.addActionListener(this);
      Equal.addActionListener(this);

      txt.setBounds(35,15,360,50);
      txt2.setBounds(0,330,100,20);
      txtotp.setBounds(59,30,270,20);

      btn7.setBounds(35,85,50,50);
      btn8.setBounds(95,85,50,50);
      btn9.setBounds(155,85,50,50);
      btn4.setBounds(35,145,50,50);
      btn5.setBounds(95,145,50,50);
      btn6.setBounds(155,145,50,50);
      btn1.setBounds(35,205,50,50);
      btn2.setBounds(95,205,50,50);
      btn3.setBounds(155,205,50,50);
      btnP.setBounds(95,265,50,50);
      btn0.setBounds(35,265,50,50);
      btnC.setBounds(340,85,50,50);
      opPlus.setBounds(280,145,50,50);
      opMult.setBounds(340,145,50,50);
      opMinu.setBounds(280,205,50,50);
      opDivi.setBounds(340,205,50,50);
      Equal.setBounds(280,265,110,50);
      txt.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
        System.out.println("me==="+me.getSource());

         ActionEvent ae = new ActionEvent(me.getSource(), me.getID(), me.paramString());
        System.out.println("ae==="+ae.getSource()); 
    }
  });


      Font font = new Font("Times New Roman",Font.BOLD,20);
      textField.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
      textField.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 20));
      textField.setEditable(false);
      textField.setBounds(35, 317, 360, 30);

      getContentPane().add(textField);
      txt.setFont(font);
      txt.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);

      c.add(txt);
      c.add(btn7);
      c.add(btn1);
      c.add(btn2);
      c.add(btn3);
      c.add(btn4);
      c.add(btn5);
      c.add(btn6);
      c.add(btn8);
      c.add(btn9);
      c.add(btn0);
      c.add(btnC);
      c.add(opPlus);
      c.add(opMult);
      c.add(opDivi);
      c.add(opMinu);
      c.add(Equal);
      c.add(btnP);


       Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

      setSize(440,385);
       int w = getSize().width;
       int h = getSize().height;
       int x = (dim.width-w)/2;
       int y = (dim.height-h)/2;
       setLocation(x, y);
      setVisible(true);
      setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 

        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
         String input = txt.getText();
        // MouseEvent me = null ;
        // ActionEvent ae = new ActionEvent(me.getSource(), me.getID(), me.paramString());

       /*  if(e.getSource()==Equal ){
             System.out.println("Welcome to hell");
         }
         else if(e.getSource()==btnC)
         {
             System.out.println("Welcome to hell you should empty list");
         }
         else{
              if(e.getSource()==btn1){
                  txt.setText(input + "1");
                  System.out.println(input);
                 } 
                  else if(e.getSource()==btn2){
                  txt.setText(input + "2");
                 }
                 else if(e.getSource()==btn3){
                  txt.setText(input + "3");
                 }
                 else if(e.getSource()==btn4){
                  txt.setText(input + "4");
                 }
                 else if(e.getSource()==btn5){
                  txt.setText(input + "5");
                 }
                 else if(e.getSource()==btn6){
                  txt.setText(input + "6");
                 }
                 else if(e.getSource()==btn7){
                  txt.setText(input + "7");
                 }
                 else if(e.getSource()==btn8){
                  txt.setText(input + "8");
                 }
                 else if(e.getSource()==btn9){
                  txt.setText(input + "9");
                 }
                 else if(e.getSource()==btn0){
                  txt.setText(input + "0");
                 }
                 else if(e.getSource()==btnP){
                  txt.setText(input + ".");
                 }
                 else if(e.getSource()==opPlus){
                  fnum = Double.parseDouble(txt.getText());
                  op = "+";

                   txt.setText("");
                 }
                 else if(e.getSource() == opMinu){
                  fnum = Double.parseDouble(txt.getText());
                  op = "-";

                     txt.setText("");
                 }
                 else if(e.getSource() == opMult){
                  fnum = Double.parseDouble(txt.getText());
                  op = "x";

                     txt.setText("");

                 }
                 else if(e.getSource() == opDivi){
                  fnum = Double.parseDouble(txt.getText());
                  op = "/";

                  txt.setText("");
                 }

         }
        */

         if(e.getSource()==btnC){
       txt.setText("");
         } 
         else if(e.getSource()==btn1){
          txt.setText(input + "1");
          System.out.println(input);
         } 
          else if(e.getSource()==btn2){
          txt.setText(input + "2");
         }
         else if(e.getSource()==btn3){
          txt.setText(input + "3");
         }
         else if(e.getSource()==btn4){
          txt.setText(input + "4");
         }
         else if(e.getSource()==btn5){
          txt.setText(input + "5");
         }
         else if(e.getSource()==btn6){
          txt.setText(input + "6");
         }
         else if(e.getSource()==btn7){
          txt.setText(input + "7");
         }
         else if(e.getSource()==btn8){
          txt.setText(input + "8");
         }
         else if(e.getSource()==btn9){
          txt.setText(input + "9");
         }
         else if(e.getSource()==btn0){
          txt.setText(input + "0");
         }
         else if(e.getSource()==btnP){
          txt.setText(input + ".");
         }
         else if(e.getSource()==opPlus){
          fnum = Double.parseDouble(txt.getText());
          op = "+";
          enterdVal.add(txt.getText());
          enterdVal.add(op);
           txt.setText("");
         }
         else if(e.getSource() == opMinu){
          fnum = Double.parseDouble(txt.getText());
          op = "-";
          enterdVal.add(txt.getText());
          enterdVal.add(op);

             txt.setText("");
         }
         else if(e.getSource() == opMult){
          fnum = Double.parseDouble(txt.getText());
          op = "x";
          enterdVal.add(txt.getText());
          enterdVal.add(op);
             txt.setText("");

         }
         else if(e.getSource() == opDivi){
          fnum = Double.parseDouble(txt.getText());
          op = "/";
          enterdVal.add(txt.getText());
          enterdVal.add(op);
          txt.setText("");
         }
         else if(e.getSource()==Equal){
          snum = Double.parseDouble(txt.getText());
          enterdVal.add(txt.getText());
          if(op.equals("+"))
          {
           total=fnum+snum; }
          else if(op.equals("x")){
           total = fnum*snum;
          }
          else if(op.equals("/")){
           total = fnum/snum;
          }
          else if(op.equals("-"))
          { total = fnum-snum;
          }
          textField.setText(""+total);
          txt.setText(""+enterdVal.toString());

         }

        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
           Calculator Cal = new Calculator();
        }
    }
```

`

Can any support me in my idea.

I have tried to write some code but I am not able get it.
Any suggestion are welcomed..

When I add MouseAdapter is gives me:

```
    me===javax.swing.JTextField[,35,15,360x50,layout=javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$UpdateHandler,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.BorderUIResource$CompoundBorderUIResource@911f71,flags=296,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,caretColor=sun.swing.PrintColorUIResource[r=51,g=51,b=51],disabledTextColor=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=184,g=207,b=229],editable=true,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=0,left=0,bottom=0,right=0],selectedTextColor=sun.swing.PrintColorUIResource[r=51,g=51,b=51],selectionColor=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=184,g=207,b=229],columns=0,columnWidth=0,command=,horizontalAlignment=RIGHT]
ae===javax.swing.JTextField[,35,15,360x50,layout=javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$UpdateHandler,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.BorderUIResource$CompoundBorderUIResource@911f71,flags=296,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,caretColor=sun.swing.PrintColorUIResource[r=51,g=51,b=51],disabledTextColor=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=184,g=207,b=229],editable=true,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=0,left=0,bottom=0,right=0],selectedTextColor=sun.swing.PrintColorUIResource[r=51,g=51,b=51],selectionColor=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=184,g=207,b=229],columns=0,columnWidth=0,command=,horizontalAlignment=RIGHT]
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried and why it is not producing the desired result.  This will make it much more clear what you are asking.

Comment: How do you envision "*click on 3*"? Do you plan to convert your text into array of buttons?

Comment: @PM77-1 thats what I am not able to get how to go ahead with that. I thought of going ahead with mouseevent but it does not produce any result. If I convert all my text to array of button then how to get the value out of it.

Comment: @jzd I have posted the code but the mouse event part is commented.

Comment: @PM77-1 If I convert it to array of button  also I think It won't do job because in output textfield only text can be displayed.

Comment: What do you expect this to do `ae==="+ae.getSource()`? What makes your last code block (the output) relevant to your question?

Comment: @peeskillet sorry, really confused can't say , m struggling with it. Ideally it should be the value on which I clicked in textfield.

Comment: This is way too much code, need a SSCCE.

Answer (score 0):

It's going to be unneccesarily hard to do, when it is coded as it is. Take a look at the Windows calculator. In that, while you're entering the calculation, it prints the entire calculation *while you type it in*. Then when the user hits "=", it runs through a loop, that does the actual calculations. Forget about putting it all into an array "on-the-go". Just keep appending to the text in the calculation-textfield, until the user hits "=".

Then you can leave the calculation-text there, and have the result in a separate textfield (as you do now). THEN, you can simply edit the textfield with the calculation, and hit "=" again, and you will get a new result.

It will probably take a bit of rewriting, but it will be a prettier and more organized solution for your purposes.